# Seperate homeicons for android and ios using sap.m.Shell

Tags: jquery, sapui5

The current ui5 documentation dynamically selects the icon based on the device type like phone,tablet e.t.c.:

```
function(Shell, ComponentContainer) {
            new Shell({
                homeIcon: {
                    favicon: "img/favicon.ico",
                    phone: "img/logo_57px.png",
                    "phone@2": "img/logo_114px.png",
                    tablet: "img/logo_72px.png",
                    "tablet@2": "img/logo_144px.png",
                    precomposed: false // whether the home icons already have some glare effects (for iOS)
                },
                app: new ComponentContainer({
                    component: createdComponent,
                    height: "100%"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
```

Is there a possibility of creating separate homeicons for android and ios devices so that when the application is downloaded and installed in an android device one homeicon can be shown and a seperate icon if it is installed in a ios device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI5 has a [Device API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.Device.os) to get the OS of the browser.
If you create a device model as explained in [Step 36: Device Adaptation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2), you should be able to use [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) on the Icons and switch their paths.